# Trying to pass a local variable to my ngAside controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using `ngAside` to display some data. The data depends on a variable chosen by the user so I need to pass an Id to `ngAside`'s controller.

Right now my controller looks like this:

```
$aside.open({
    templateUrl: 'details.html',
    placement: position,
    size: 'lg',
    backdrop: true, 
    locals: {
        mode: "create"
    },
    controller: function Ctrl($scope, $uibModalInstance, mode) {
        $scope.test = mode;
        $scope.ok = function (e) {
            $uibModalInstance.close();
            e.stopPropagation();
        };
        $scope.cancel = function (e) {
            $uibModalInstance.dismiss();
            e.stopPropagation();
        };
    }
})
```

I have based this on what I've seen written on `ngMaterial` [here](https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/src/core/services/compiler/compiler.spec.js#L122).

It is not working as expected though and Im getting

```
Unknown provider: modeProvider <- mode
```

How can I fix this and be able to pass variables to be displayed on my `ngAside` template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to inject "mode" variable in a controller, my guess would be using the standard "**resolve**" parameter.

```
$aside.open({
  templateUrl: 'details.html',
  placement: position,
  size: 'lg',
  backdrop: true, 
  resolve: {
    mode: function() {
      return "create";
    }
  },
  controller: function Ctrl($scope, $uibModalInstance, mode) {
    [...]
  }
});
```

Basically, for each controller parameter that is not registered in the Dependency Injection list, you need to provide a function which will return the value you want to be injected in the variable.

This function :

```
  mode: function() {
    return "create";
  }
```

Will be executed and its return value will populate the "mode" controller argument.